# Why does numpy.dot behave in this way?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to understand why numpy's `dot` function behaves as it does:

```
M = np.ones((9, 9))
V1 = np.ones((9,))
V2 = np.ones((9, 5))
V3 = np.ones((2, 9, 5))
V4 = np.ones((3, 2, 9, 5))
```

Now `np.dot(M, V1)` and `np.dot(M, V2)` behave as
expected. But for `V3` and `V4` the result surprises
me:

```
>>> np.dot(M, V3).shape
(9, 2, 5)
>>> np.dot(M, V4).shape
(9, 3, 2, 5)
```

I expected `(2, 9, 5)` and `(3, 2, 9, 5)` respectively. On the other hand, `np.matmul`
does what I expect: the matrix multiply is broadcast
over the first *N - 2* dimensions of the second argument and
the result has the same shape:

```
>>> np.matmul(M, V3).shape
(2, 9, 5)
>>> np.matmul(M, V4).shape
(3, 2, 9, 5)
```

So my question is this: what is the rationale for
`np.dot` behaving as it does? Does it serve some particular purpose,
or is it the result of applying some general rule?

Comment: this is actually explained in the numpy docs for dot and matmul

Answer (score 7):

From [the docs for `np.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

> For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication, and for 1-D arrays to inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation). For N dimensions it is a **sum product** over the **last axis of `a`** and the **second-to-last of `b`**:
>
> ```
> dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])
> ```

For `np.dot(M, V3)`,

```
(9, 9), (2, 9, 5) --> (9, 2, 5)
```

For `np.dot(M, V4)`,

```
(9, 9), (3, 2, 9, 5) --> (9, 3, 2, 5)
```

The strike-through represents dimensions that are summed over, and are therefore not present in the result.

---

In contrast, [`np.matmul`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) treats *N*-dimensional arrays as 'stacks' of 2D matrices:

> The behavior depends on the arguments in the following way.
>
> - If both arguments are 2-D they are multiplied like conventional matrices.
> - If either argument is N-D, N > 2, **it is treated as a stack of matrices residing in the last two indexes** and broadcast accordingly.

The same reductions are performed in both cases, but the order of the axes is different. `np.matmul` essentially does the equivalent of:

```
for ii in range(V3.shape[0]):
    out1[ii, :, :] = np.dot(M[:, :], V3[ii, :, :])
```

and

```
for ii in range(V4.shape[0]):
    for jj in range(V4.shape[1]):
        out2[ii, jj, :, :] = np.dot(M[:, :], V4[ii, jj, :, :])
```

Comment: Here is another example: ```a1 = np.random.rand(3,4);
a2 = np.random.rand(10, 4, 1);
A = (a1 @ a2);
B = np.array([a1 @ a2[i,:,0] for i in range(10)]);
assert A.shape == B.shape;
assert np.allclose(A.squeeze(), B)```

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation of [`numpy.matmul`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html):

> `matmul` differs from `dot` in two important ways.
>
> - Multiplication by scalars is not allowed.
> - Stacks of matrices are broadcast together as if the matrices were elements.

In conclusion, this is the standard matrix-matrix multiplication you would expect.

On the other hand, [`numpy.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) is only equivalent to the matrix-matrix multiplication for two-dimensional arrays. For larger dimensions, ...

> it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last of b:
>
> ```
> dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])
> ```

[source: documentation of [`numpy.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)]

This resembles the inner (dot) product. In case of vectors, `numpy.dot` returns the dot product. Arrays are considered collections of vectors, and the dot product of them is returned.

Answer (score 3):

For the why :

`dot`  and `matmult` are both generalizations of 2D*2D matrix multiplication. But they are a lot of possible choices, according to mathematics properties, broadcasting rules, ...

The choices are  for `dot` and `matmul` are very different:
[image]

For `dot`, some dimensions (green here) are dedicated to the first array ,
others (blue) for the second.

`matmul` need an alignement of stacks regarding to broadcasting rules.

Numpy is born in an image analysis context, and `dot` can manage easily some tasks by a `out=dot(image(s),transformation(s))` way. (see the dot docs in early version of  [numpy book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIaXA.png), p92).

As an illustration :

```
from pylab import *
image=imread('stackoverflow.png')

identity=eye(3)
NB=ones((3,3))/3
swap_rg=identity[[1,0,2]]
randoms=[rand(3,3) for _ in range(6)]

transformations=[identity,NB,swap_rg]+randoms
out=dot(image,transformations)

for k in range(9): 
    subplot(3,3,k+1)
    imshow (out[...,k,:])
```

[image: so]

The modern `matmul` can do the same thing as the old `dot`, but the *stack of matrix* must be take in account.  (`matmul(image,transformations[:,None])` here).

No doubt that it is better in other contexts.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent `einsum` expressions are:

```
In [92]: np.einsum('ij,kjm->kim',M,V3).shape
Out[92]: (2, 9, 5)
In [93]: np.einsum('ij,lkjm->lkim',M,V4).shape
Out[93]: (3, 2, 9, 5)
```

Expressed this way, the `dot` equivalent, 'ij,lkjm->ilkm', looks just as natural as the 'matmul' equivalent, 'ij,lkjm->lkim'.